# Can't Get Postgres working with Spring Boot, Hibernate, Gradle and Heroku

Tags: spring, postgresql, heroku, jdbc, gradle

I have been trying to deploy my app to heroku, it was previously running locally successfully using a hibernate database. Now I am attempting to swap in Postgres database instead and deploy it to heroku and have been unsuccessful. I have two issues currently:

**1) I cannot get my app to run locally with the `heroku local` command.**

**2) I cannot get my app to run externally when deployed to heroku.**

For **(1)** I run `./gradlew stage` and then run `heroku local`.

The error I get is: `web.1 |  Error: Unable to access jarfile target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar`

For **(2)** I deploy my code to github and it gets automatically deployed to heroku. The build is successful.

When I open the app, I get an application error and my heroku logs say the error is caused by: `Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections`

[I am following the instructions provided by heroku.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-spring-mvc-hibernate)

**`ProcFile`**

```
web:    java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

**`META-INF/persistence.xml`**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"  version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="com.doronzehavi.newsitem" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.doronzehavi.newsitemweb.model.item.NewsItem</class>
        <class>com.doronzehavi.newsitemweb.model.source.NewsSource</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**`META-INF/Spring/applicationContext.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>
    <context:spring-configured/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.doronzehavi.newsitemweb">
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
    </context:component-scan>
    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="#{ 'jdbc:postgresql://' + @dbUrl.getHost() + ':' + @dbUrl.getPort() + @dbUrl.getPath() }"/>
        <property name="username" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0] }"/>
        <property name="password" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[1] }"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT version();"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="java.net.URI" id="dbUrl">
      <constructor-arg value="${DATABASE_URL}"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**`META-INF/Spring/database.properties`**

```
database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
database.url=jdbc\:postgresql\://localhost\:5432
database.username=
database.password=
```

**`build.gradle`**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.4.3.RELEASE'
    id 'war'
}

group 'com.doronzehavi'
version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    baseName = 'newsitemweb'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

task stage{
    dependsOn build
}

springBoot {
    mainClass = "com.doronzehavi.newsitemweb.Application"
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-orm:4.2.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-dbcp:8.0.32'
    compile 'com.github.jsimone:webapp-runner:8.0.30.2'
    compile 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.191'
    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1201-jdbc4'
}
```

Comment: Your persistence unit doesn't know how to create connections.

Comment: Hi Mark, could you elaborate on what steps I could take to identify the solution here?

Comment: I can only see that your persistence.xml is missing a reference to a datasource (or jdbc-url), and - although you didn't post a stacktrace - I guess that the exception is a result from that (also the reason why I posted a comment, not an answer). Unfortunately I'm not 100% sure about that, and I don't have time to dig into it further.